# Android - openOptionsMenu doesn't work in onCreate

Tags: android

Is there any other way to call openOptionsMenu after activity is displayed without using something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                openOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Reference:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_frm/thread/b10a8ea840c07725/1ce48bb147a3ed1a?#1ce48bb147a3ed1a

EDIT: I would appreciate example like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Now I guess something like Window.Callback.onAttachedToWindow(...) should be done?
}
```

Comment: That solution is really quite fragile

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I looked at `Activity` again, and it has had the method [onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29), inherited from [Window.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29), since API level 5. If you are using this level, then you simply have to override this method in your `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

If you are using a version prior to 5, then you have to override the [onAttachedToWindow method in View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29) instead. This is very easy if your `View` is created in code. If it is created in XMl, then it isn't that much harder -  you should find the [instructions here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) helpful.

Comment: And where should I insert this override, as Activity doesn't have onAttachedToWindow?

Comment: Can you please give me complete example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @kape123: I did some more research. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Yeah... definitely it's clear now (I'm using API 4)... thanks a lot for your help! (I'll accept your answer and give it bounty ASAP)

Answer (score -1):

My solution

```
//Open menu manually from code 
    Timer timing = new Timer();
    timing.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                /**
                 * {@inheritDoc}
                 */
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            openOptionsMenu();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: ... that's worse version of code I already posted in my question

Comment: hey, did you try it? I am using it in my own application on the market.

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to use timer-based scheduling during the startup/loading, especially if you can use a dedicated callback.