# How to simulate home, back, menu, search, task and volume buttons?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I want to simulate all physical buttons of our Android devices.

So is there a way to simulate:

- BACK BUTTON
- HOME BUTTON
- MENU BUTTON
- SEARCH BUTTON
- TASK BUTTON
- VOLUME (+ AND -) BUTTONS

Comment: You want access those buttons from java code?

Comment: there are lots of solution on GOOGLE..

Comment: @RajeshRajaram No I want to go to home or show menu (etc etc) programmatically

Comment: @AnandTiwari I found only Home Button code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752319/android-simulate-home-click

Answer (score 17):

Create a KeyEvent and publish it.

```
KeyEvent kdown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(kdown);
KeyEvent kup = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(kup);
```

Comment: Many thanks..but I want to do this programmatically and not only from an activity...

Comment: This is exactly "programmatically" and you can always have a reference of your activity to call this method (you are not forced to call it within your activity).

Comment: @Aleksander Gralak : Your code does not call the `activity.onBackPressed` method btw...

Comment: You need to call it for both action down and action up. Like so

this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));

Comment: this method doesn't work anymore: ```
ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent can only be called from within the same library group prefix(referenced groupId=androidx.core)```

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate pressing buttons even your app is closed, but you'll need Accessibility permission:

Create service extended from `AccessibilityService`:

```
class ExampleAccessService:AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onInterrupt() {
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    }
    
    fun doAction(){
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_QUICK_SETTINGS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN)
    }
}
```

*Call `doAction()` where you want action*

Add to `Manifest`:

```
<application
...
    <service
        android:name=".ExampleAccessService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="Name of servise" // it will be viewed in Settings->Accessibility->Services
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
    </service>
...
</application>
```

**accessibility_service_config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="false"
    android:description="your description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:packageNames="your app package, ex: ex: com.example.android"
    android:settingsActivity="your settings activity ex: com.example.android.MainActivity" />
```

for more info look at [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service)

Answer (score 0):

If you test your application's specific component such as `Activity` so you may use `InstrumentationTestCase`'s [`sendKeys()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#sendKeys%28java.lang.String%29)method, passing there any combination of keys. Also you can use [`TouchUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) to simulate tapping, dragging and clicking actions

Answer (score 0):

Simulation for following keys:

-BACK BUTTON : override onBackPressed() in current activity.

-MENU BUTTON : you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777098/android-openoptionsmenu-doesnt-work-in-oncreate) and also openOptionsMenu(),  [menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

you should also look at [this](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.in/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html) blog.

Comment: back button doesn't always close the current activity, especially if the activity has "onBackPressed" being implemented in a different way.

Comment: Also this won't work if you want to simulate the button click as part of a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android dispatchKeyEvent override method.

Answer (score -1):

Use `onKeyListener` for overriding the physical buttons in your device. See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html).

The [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) class have all the values for the physical buttons and on screen keyboard on your device. For Example [`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME) substitutes for the home button in the device.

Google it, you can find a lot of examples for `KEYCODE` events

Answer (score -2):

Try this your activity

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   
{
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
 {

 }
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
 {

 }
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
 {

 }
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
 {

 }
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks but I don't want to pick buttons event but to simulate them

Comment: wrong direction.. the question clearly states simulate, not catch